Solving the functional equation $\displaystyle f(x+y+z)\equiv\frac{f(x)+f(y)+f(z)}{1-f(x)f(y)f(z)}$.
The tangent function function satisfies the very pretty functional equation
$$f(x+y) \equiv \frac{f(x)+f(y)}{1-f(x)f(y)}$$
In fact, so does the function $f(x)\equiv \tan(a x)$ for all $a\in\mathbb R$, and I know of no other solution.
This inspired me to consider the three-variable version of this equation, that is,
$$f(x+y+z) \equiv \frac{f(x)+f(y)+f(z)}{1-f(x)f(y)f(z)}$$
Tangent is no longer a solution. I wonder if one even exists, besides the null function. Here is my progress so far.
For $y, z\leftarrow 0$ we get
$$f(x) \equiv \frac{f(x) + 2f(0)}{1-f(x)f(0)^2}\implies f(x)^2 f(0)^2\equiv -2f(0)$$
If $f(0)\ne 0$, this equation would lead us to a constant value for $f(x)$, so $f(0)$ must be $0$ if we want an interesting solution.
But then, for $z\leftarrow 0$, we get
$$f(x+y)\equiv \frac{f(x)+f(y)+f(0)}{1-f(x)f(y)f(0)} = f(x)+f(y)$$
and so $f$ satisfies Cauchy's equation. But this implies $f(x)f(y)f(z)\equiv 0$ and thus $f(x)\equiv 0$, so finding a non-trivial solution seem hopeless. However, this only happens if we assume $0$ is on $f$'s domain. Asking otherwise is not a big stretch as the tangent is not well defined for all real numbers as well, so this is what I'll be assuming from now on. By the way, lets discuss the domain of this function.
Usually, when given a functional equation, we are asked to solve it over some given domain. However, I honestly have no idea what subset of the real numbers would be appropriate here. I'm sure you could find a non trivial inconstructible answer in some very degenerate subset of $\mathbb R$. If possible, I would like to have an answer defined on a reasonable domain, e.g. an interval, the complement of a countable set or a set with total measure. However, I think one condition could override this one: I would like $f$ to be surjective, or, at least, surjective over the positive real numbers.
Here is some more work.

If $f$ is continuous, then $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$ doesn't exist.

Of course, a continuous solution would be very desirable. Suppose $f$ is continuous, then. If $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$ exists and is finite, then we stumble at the same problem as before. If else $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0} |f(x)| = \infty$, applying the limit $y, z\to 0$ on the equation yields $f(x)\equiv 0$. $\square$
We can resolve this by making so that $f$ oscillates around $0$, or simply by making to that $f$ is undefined around $0$. This already makes $f$ to be not as nice as the tangent function.

$0\not\in Im(f)$.

So my hope for a surjective solution is doomed. In fact, suppose $f(a) = 0$ for some $a\in\mathbb R$. For $z\leftarrow a$ we get
$$f(x+y+a)\equiv f(x)+f(y)$$
For $x\leftarrow x+a$ and $y\leftarrow y-a$ we get
$$f(x+y+a)\equiv f(x+a)+f(y-a)$$
But then
$$f(x)+f(y)\equiv f(x+a)+f(y-a)\implies f(x+a)-f(x)\equiv f(y)-f(y-a)$$
so $f$ is $a$-periodic, therefore $f(x+y)\equiv f(x)+f(y)$ and $f(x)\equiv 0$ as before. $\square$

Another trivial solution is the constant function $f(x) = -\sqrt[3]{2}$.

A nice question would be if there are any other solutions to the two-variable functional equation.

I think if the domain $D_f$ of the function $f$ is a proper subset of the real numbers then we should be accurate with the interpretation of the equation. For instance, already for the first equation for the tangent function $\tan x$, it can happen that $x+y\not\in D_{\tan}$ for $x,y\in D_{\tan}$.

I think that usually three variables provide too many freedom degrees for a functional equation, that provides its solutions to be trivial or do not exist at all.
Let $z\leftarrow -y$. Then $f(y)+f(-y)=-f(x)^2f(y)f(-y)$. If the function $f$ is not constant, then there exists $y$ in the domain of $f$ with $f(y)\ne 0$. Then $f(-y)\ne 0$, and so $f(x)^2$ is constant.
Moreover, suppose that for some $x\ne 0$ the set $S_x=x\cdot \{1,2,3,5,6\}$ belongs to the domain of $f$.
We show that there are only a few possibilities for $f|S_x$.
Put  $t=f(x)$ and $s=f(2x)$. Then $f(3x)=\frac{3t}{1-t^3}$. The following presentation will be rather brief, because I used Mathcad for my calculations.
The equality
$$f(5x)=\frac{2f(2x)+f(x)}{1-f(2x)^2f(x)}=\frac{2f(x)+f(3x)}{1-f(x)^2f(3x)}$$
implies that $$P(s)=(2t^5-5t^2)s^2+(8t^3-2)s+2t^4+4t=0.$$
The polynomial $P(s)$ has the discriminant
$$D(t)=-2(2t^3+1)(t^3-5-3\sqrt{3})(t^3-5+3\sqrt{3}).$$
The equality
$$f(6x)=\frac{f(x)+f(2x)+f(3x)}{1-f(x)f(2x)f(3x)}=\frac{3f(2x)}{1-f(2x)^3}$$
implies that
$$Q(s)=(t^3-1)s^4+(t^4-4t)s^3+9t^2s^2+(2t^3-2)s-t^4+4t=0.$$
Since the polynomials $P(s)$ and $Q(s)$ have a common root, their resultant
$$t^4(t^3+2)^3(2t^3+1)(8t^{12}-92t^9+390t^6-239t^3+14)=0.$$
So we have one of the following cases for $t=f(x)$.

$t^4=0$. Then $t=0$ and $-2s=P(s)=0$. Then it is easy to show that $f(r)=0$ for each $r\in S_x$.

$t^3+2=0$. Then $t=-\sqrt[3]{2}$ and so $f(3x)=t$ and then $f(5x)=t$. Since $P(s)=-9t^2s^2-18s$, either $s=0$ or $s=t$. But if $s=0$ then
$0=f(6x)=f(x)+f(3x)=2t$, a contradiction. So $s=t$ and then $f(6x)=t$.
That is $f(r)=-\sqrt[3]{2}$ for each $r\in S_x$.

$2t^3+1=0$. Then $t=-\frac 1{\sqrt[3]{2}}$ and so $f(3x)=2t=-\sqrt[3]{4}$ and then
$f(5x)=2t$. Moreover, since $D(t)=0$, we have
$$s=\frac{2-8t^3}{2(2t^5-5t^2)}=-\frac 1{2t^2}=t$$
and so $f(6x)=t$.

$8t^{12}-92t^9+390t^6-239t^3+14=0$. There are only two real roots,
$t=0.403024\dots$ and $t=0.867377\dots$. In both cases $D(t)>0$ which provides two roots $s$ of the polynomial $P(s)$ for each case. I did not check which of these roots are also roots of $Q(s)$.



This approach is similar to @Alex Ravsky's.
We assume that $\pm x$ and $\pm 3x$ are in the domain of $f$.
Then
\begin{align}
f(3x) &= \frac{3f(x)}{1-f(x)^3} 
    & (y,z)\to (x,x) \\
f(-x) &= \frac{2f(x)+f(-3x)}{1-f(x)^2 f(-3x)}
    & (y,z)\to (x,-3x) \\
f(x) &= \frac{f(x)+f(3x)+f(-3x)}{1-f(x)f(3x)f(-3x)}
    & (y,z)\to (3x,-3x) \\
f(3x) &= \frac{f(x)+f(-x)+f(3x)}{1-f(x)f(-x)f(3x)}.
    & (y,z)\to (-x,3x) 
\end{align}
This system reduces straightforwardly to
$$f(x)^7(f(x)^3+2)=0,$$
resulting in four constant solutions.

The last equation has only two real roots.

@AlexRavsky: True. I appreciate your close reading.

user26872 has almost finished the problem, let's finish it. Let $S$ be the set of roots of the polynomial $u (u^3+2)$. user26872 shows that every value of $f$ is in $S$. (This is true whether we consider real or complex-valued functions. If we want real-valued functions, then $|S| =2$, for complex-valued, $|S|=4$.) I will show that $f$ must be constant valued, with value equal to one of the values in $S$.
So, let $f : \mathbb{R} \to S$  be a nonconstant function obeying the functional equation. Suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that $f(x) \neq f(y)$. Switching $x$ and $y$ if necessary, assume that $f(x) \neq 0$. Plugging $(x,x,y)$ into the equation, we get
$$\frac{2 f(x) + f(y)}{1-f(x)^2 f(y)} = f(2x+y) \in S \qquad (\ast)$$
But there are no values of $f(x)$, $f(y) \in S$ with $f(x) \neq f(y)$ and $f(x) \neq 0$, for which $(\ast)$ holds.

The equation $u(u^3+2)$ has only two real roots.

Correct, it was unclear to me whether $f$ was supposed to be real or complex valued. This solution covers both. Oh, I see a place where my writing was sloppy; I'll improve.
